# Error when running Django tests just for admin

Tags: python, django

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#contrib-apps), I can run tests for django.contrib.admin like so

```
# from django/tests
./runtests.py --settings=test_sqlite django.contrib.admin
```

When I do this, however, I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runtests.py", line 337, in <module>
    options.failfast, args)
  File "./runtests.py", line 180, in django_tests
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests=extra_tests)
  File "/Users/joshuafialkoff/.virtualenvs/bankr-env/src/django/django/test/simple.py", line 369, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "/Users/joshuafialkoff/.virtualenvs/bankr-env/src/django/django/test/simple.py", line 254, in build_suite
    suite.addTest(build_test(label))
  File "/Users/joshuafialkoff/.virtualenvs/bankr-env/src/django/django/test/simple.py", line 102, in build_test
    app_module = get_app(parts[0])
  File "/Users/joshuafialkoff/.virtualenvs/bankr-env/src/django/django/db/models/loading.py", line 160, in get_app
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" % app_label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label django could not be found
```

At the same time, if I run:

```
./runtests.py --settings=test_sqlite
```

the tests begin running - but I don't want to run the whole suite. I'm running this from the repo tag 1.5.2. How do I go about running tests just for admin?

Comment: There's a difference in the test documentation between the development verion's docs (the one you [linked](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#contrib-apps) to) and the [docs for 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#contrib-apps) . My suggestion from the difference is to just use the app_label `admin` instead of `django.contrib.admin`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Dave, that got it running. However, it's not running any tests. I thought that might be because they're all Selenium tests so I installed that package. Still, no dice.